# Lazy initialization of an object using reflection

Tags: c#, lazy-initialization

I would like to do lazy initialization of the below call. I know the type of T while constructing the object.

```
T facade = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), param);
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could subclass `Lazy<T>`, like this:

```
public class LazyActivator<T> : Lazy<T>
{
    public LazyActivator(params object[] args) : base(() => (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), args))
    {
    }
}
```

then:

```
LazyActivator<List<int>> lazyList = new LazyActivator<List<int>>(5);
```

and if you need the `List<int>` (that has `Capacity == 5`)

```
List<int> list = lazyList.Value;
```